# update ACA_CHECK_HISTORY set Datecolumn=CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),getdate(),103)

Tags: java, mysql

I am using `mysql server 5.X`

```
update ACA_CHECK_HISTORY set Datecolumn=CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),getdate(),103);
```

I am getting syntax error.

Comment: Which error did you get?

Comment: That's one of a zillion differences between Sybase and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try using MySQL syntax and not SQL Server syntax:

```
update ACA_CHECK_HISTORY
    set CREATED_DATE = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Oh, wait, that's not quite what you want.  It is better than what you want.

First, you should store date/time values in the *native* format in the database.  If, for some reason, you cannot do this, then use an ISO standard format -- such as YYYY-MM-DD.  This works for sorting and comparisons, which makes it very useful.

You can convert the value to an output format when presenting it to users.  You seem to want the format `'%d/%m/%Y'`.  Nothing wrong with that format.  It is just a presentation format and should not be stored in the data.

Comment: I used this  "update ACA_CHECK_HISTORY
    set CREATED_DATE = dateformat(now(), '%Y-%m-%d'); "    But it says Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: FUNCTION envisa.dateformat does not exist

Comment: @PravinGajbhiye . . . That was a typo.  There is an underscore in the function name.

Answer (score 0):

If that column is a DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatype, then simply do

```
update ACA_CHECK_HISTORY
    set CREATED_DATE = NOW();
```

Better yet, you can avoid the UPDATE entirely if you use a TIMESTAMP with suitable DEFAULT.

Comment: Actualy I am geting the copy of data from another table including datetime. Both have datetime data type. And the date geting store is as 22-Mar-15 12:26:24. But i want date,month and year so that i can get the list of history for perticular date.

Comment: If you store it in one of those three datatypes, there are lot of functions with which you can extract date, etc.